# Visual Studio - White Text on Button Text in "Properties" Window

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, user-interface, designer

In The Properties Windows within Visual Studio and subsidiary dialogs (like the collection editor window pictured in the attached screenshot), the Text on the Buttons is white on light gray:

[image: Visual Studio Properties Window]

It seems that neither resetting the dark theme back to defaults (Environment -> General) seems to fix this, nor did some of the settings I've been fiddling with under Environment -> Fonts and Colors. (Also note how the text in the combobox next to the "Add" button is black)

Question: Where / How can I change this particular setting for the button text colors (or alternatively, the background color for the buttons) ?

For all it matters, I'm on Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 0):

These look like Win 7 style buttons. If you are on Windows 7, take a look at this:

http://www.pallareviews.com/1109/advanced-appearance-settings-windows-8-and-7/